# how to run command onn ubuntu startup

Tags: ubuntu, openconnect

I have configured OpenConnect server on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server

The problem is that, time to time some unknown users process takes port on which OCserver is running (port 900)

So I decided to make scheduled reboot, but after reboot I have to manually start OCServer on server

That's not comfortable...

How can I make run command on startup of system automatically?

```
sudo ocserv -c /etc/ocserv/config
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit `/etc/rc.local` and add your command before `exit 0` it will executed at the end of startup.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It's realy working even with sudo commands